# Inspect value of inline return during debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, return

I'm doing some mobile development and sometimes things are easiest to debug by attaching to the server. For the sake of brevity, I like to write something like this:

```
Public Function GetData(parameters) As FuzzBomb
    Using data As New PersistentDataAccessLayer()
        Return data.MakeStateChangingCall(parameters)
    End Using
End Function
```

However, if you have a string of function calls written this way (i.e. `Return GetValueFromSomeFunction`), it's really hard to inspect the value being returned while debugging.

Since there are side effects, I can't simply copy/paste the function call into the watch window. I could assign the results to a temporary variable... but that seems ugly to me:

```
Using data As New PersistentDataAccessLayer()
    Dim result = data.MakeStateChangingCall(parameters)
    Return result
End Using
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This features is supported in Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1. Needed values will be appear in Autos window. You can find feature description in [Somasegar's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/26/visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx).
2. In old version of Visual Studio and .NET you can use [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): just write `data.MakeStateChangingCall(parameters)` from debugged function and Visual Studio will evaluate target value (result of function).

Comment: That's a neat feature in VS2013. I believe option 2 would not work if my function has side-effects since I'd be calling the function once in the immediate window and once when I let the code run. I'd potentially get different results and change the state of the data (if I'm accessing a DB, for example).

Comment: @JeffBridgman, so, then you need Visual Studio 2013 / .NET 4.5.1.